# how to change the uinavigationbar background color without overriding drawRect:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to find a way to set a different background color for the different navigation bar  in my app (i have a few views with a nav bar each). I am not looking to override drawRect: since this applies globally across the app. Also, using the tintcolor property doesnt help since it applies to the nav bar items only.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

I have been googling for days and cant find a straight solution to this problem. how come something so simple is so hard? dont understand why its not a property of the uinavbar...

someone please help with a simple solution...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subclass `UINavigationBar` and overwrite drawRect, then use the subclass only in places where you want the different color. (and you could have a method that lets you pass the color when you initialize the subclass or something if you want lots of different colors).

Comment: where should I do that? under each view controller?

Comment: Overriding drawRect in iOS7 cause some problems. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523432/drawing-in-custom-uinavigationbar-attached-to-top

Answer (score 6):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarBackgroundImage"].CGImage;

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

as you were complaining before there is no contents properties. you need to import quartzframework

Comment: but i dont want to use an image...how can i set the background color without an image AND have a different color for the item?

Comment: Truly say, did you try my code before looking at the code. this is the way to set the tint color of navigationBar. first try this code and check whether are you getting the orangeColor or greenColor ?

Comment: Also self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarBackgroundImage"].CGImage;
 doesnt compile - looks like a casting error.

Comment: i am getting an orange color only for the item

Comment: and again, the (id) casting is not compiling. getting an error: file...Login.m: error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Cast of C pointer type 'CGImageRef' (aka 'struct CGImage *') to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast

Comment: Ok then here is the dumb solution, ask to your graphics designer to create different image with the different color with the default height of UINavigationBar and place it to UINavigationBar with respect to color.

Comment: Explicitly casting CGImageRef to id should fix the warning. For example,

CGImageRef imageRef;
...
layer.contents = (id) imageRef;

Answer (score 1):

what happens when you say self.navBar setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; in viewDidLoad of eachView. where navBar is declared as an IBOutlet UINavigationBar linked to the navigation bar in interface builder

Comment: Not looking to change image - but color. How can I apply this with colors?

Comment: First, I am not using IB. Secondly, when i write it, it only changes the color of the nav bar item. In general TintColor is meant to modify only the color of the nav bar item. Thats exactly my problem as described above.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

is working for me, very easy way.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is correct. You need to put it where you are creating the navigation controller.