# Drawing in custom UINavigationBar, attached to top

Tags: ios, cocoa, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have a subclass of `UINavigationBar`. It's `barPosition` is `UIBarPositionTopAttached`.
Than I override `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` in my subclass. The `rect`, that comes as parameter, has always 44 px height, and I can draw only inside this rect. So, I can't perform drawing over the status bar and it has default look. If I comment `-drawRect` out, than it looks as expected, navigation bar and status bar look as a whole and have 64 px height. Is there a way to achieve this effect with having overrided `-drawRect:` in subclass of `UINavigationBar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a the issue of a custom UINavigationBAr with a background image which would not appear under the translucent Status Bar on iOS 7 when I was adding the image in drawRect.

After moving the background image to the ViewControllers viewDidLoad Method, the background image then appeared under the Status Bar

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bg-ipad.png"];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}else{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bg-iphone.png"];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
// do your other stuff now …
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Yes, looks like it's impossible using overridden -drawRect. The other possibility that I found, is to override -layoutSubview method.